# sqlite3.OperationalError: near "(": syntax error

Tags: python, sublimetext

```
def confirmarsocio():
    nuevosocio = MessageBox.askquestion("Confirmar","¿Confirma el ingreso de un nuevo socio?")
    if nuevosocio == "yes": 
        conexion.execute('''create table if not exists socios (
                          id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                          documento VARCHAR(9) UNIQUE,
                          nombre VARCHAR(50),
                          apellido VARCHAR(50),
                          fechadenacimiento DATE,
                          mail varchar(70),
                          fechadeingreso DATE,
                          observaciones VARCHAR(100)
                    )''')
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO socios VALUES(null, entryDocumento.get(), entryNombre.get(), entryApellido.get(), entryNacimiento.get(), entryMail.get(), entryFechaIngreso.get() ,TextObservaciones.get())")
        conexion.commit()
        MessageBox.showinfo("Información", "Socio agregado")
```

Este es un pedazo de código. Abajo tengo unas entry donde ingreso datos. Mi idea es grabar esos datos en la base de datos.

Answer (score 4):

Cuando escribis la consulta dentro de VALUES llenalo de ' ? ' como campos tengas.
Luego cuando vas a ejectuar la consultar  pasa como segundo argumento una tupla con los valores de los campos.

Asi por ejemplo

```
cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO tabla(campo1, campo2) VALUES (?, ?) """, ("un string", 20))
```

Dentro de la tupla podes ingresar los entryX.get()

Answer (score 1):

me parece que falta unas ; en )''')

asi

```
conexion.execute('''create table if not exists socios (
                          id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                          documento VARCHAR(9) UNIQUE,
                          nombre VARCHAR(50),
                          apellido VARCHAR(50),
                          fechadenacimiento DATE,
                          mail varchar(70),
                          fechadeingreso DATE,
                          observaciones VARCHAR(100)
                    );''')
```

prueben que a veces se le olvidan, despues de horas descubri que me faltaban 1 ; al final

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el error lo tienes al momento de hacer el INSERT ya que en id le la pasas un valor null, cuando las llaves primarias no deben de ser nulas

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO socios VALUES(null, 
entryDocumento.get(), entryNombre.get(), entryApellido.get(), 
entryNacimiento.get(), entryMail.get(), entryFechaIngreso.get(),
TextObservaciones.get())")
```

Te recomendaría que lo cambies a algo como esto

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO socios(documento, nombre, apellido, 
fechadenacimiento, mail,
fechadeingreso, observaciones)
VALUES('"+entryDocumento.get()+"','"+entryNombre.get()+"','"
+entryApellido.get()+"','"+entryNacimiento.get()+"','"+entryMail.get()+"','"
+entryFechaIngreso.get()+"','"+TextObservaciones.get()+"')")
```

Comment: Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python36\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1702, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Marcos\Desktop\PhytonKraken\NuevoSocio.py", line 38, in confirmarsocio
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO socios (documento, nombre, apellido, fechadenacimiento, mail, fechadeingreso, observaciones) VALUES(entryDocumento.get(), entryNombre.get(), entryApellido.get(), entryNacimiento.get(), entryMail.get(),entryFechaIngreso.get() ,TextObservaciones.get())")
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "(": syntax error

Comment: Perdon que me quedo el código mas estructurado. Probé y me sigue dando el mismo error.

Comment: Prueba con lo siguiente
VALUES(' " + entryDocumento.get() + " ',' " + 
entryNombre.get() + " ',' " +  entryApellido.get() + " ',' " +  entryNacimiento.get() + " ',' " + entryMail.get() + " ',' " + 
entryFechaIngreso.get() + " ',' " + TextObservaciones.get() + " ')")

Ya que tus datos son fechas y texto deben de ir entre comillas simple en la sentencia SQL

Comment: TypeError: get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'index1'. Ahora me dio ese error. Esta rebelde python. Con valores fijos funciona, el tema es cuando le paso algo por parametro

Comment: Por lo que he consultado, ese error te surge porque get() está esperando que le pases algún parámetro.